# DynamoDB Local Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to develop an app (on http://whatever.dev for example) that will, once in production, use AWS DynamoDB with JavaScript (not Node). For now, we're using DynamoDB Local to be able to dev locally without hitting AWS.

The problem with DynamoDB Local is that there's no provided Access-Control-Allow-Origin header sent back from the server.

So if I do this on whatever.dev:

```
  var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({
    accessKeyId:    'thisIsSomeInvalidKey',
    secretAccessKey:'anEquallyInvalidSecret!',
    region:         'us-east-1',
    endpoint:       'http://whatever.dev:8000',
    sslEnabled:     false,
    maxRetries:     5,
    //logger:         console
  });

  dynamodb.listTables(function(err, data) {
    console.log(data)
});
```

This is what I get back:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load whatever.dev:8000. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'whatever.dev' is therefore not allowed access.

So, essentially, I'm developing locally, using DynamoDB Local yet I can't connect to it because it doesn't give me XHR allowance. Is there any way around this? Can I modify something in DynamoDB Local to obtain the proper headers?

There are no Python/Java dependencies to my project (it's purely front-end, with Backbone and RequireJS), so using one would suck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can start DynamoDB Local with the -cors argument

```
-cors <arg>             Enable CORS support for javascript against a
                        specific allow-list list the domains
                        serporated by , [use '*' for public access]
```

E.g.

```
java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar --cors "*"
```

And can open an html file with the following in the browser:

```
<html>
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.14.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({
    accessKeyId:    'thisIsSomeInvalidKey',
    secretAccessKey:'anEquallyInvalidSecret!',
    region:         'us-east-1',
    endpoint:       'http://localhost:8000',
    sslEnabled:     false,
    maxRetries:     5,
  });

  dynamodb.listTables(function(err, data) {
    console.log(data) // { TableNames: Array[0] }
  });
</script>
</html>
```

Hope that helps!