# Why does failed dynamodb query fail with cors error on localhost instead of actual error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

In my development environment, I have a local copy of Dynamodb set up, using Reactjs to connect to it.  I'm using the AWS SDK, in particular the query method for Dynamodb, to make queries.

When the query is properly structured, it runs fine.  However, if the query is poorly structured, I get a cryptic response.  The Chrome console gives me a:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/ 400 (Bad Request)
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

where localhost:8000 points to the local Dynamodb instance and localhost:3000 points to the react instance.

Most importantly, I don't get an error message dealing specifically with the mistake I've made.  For instance, I might project a field with a reserved word, which then should correctly not work.  However, I would expect an error saying "such and such word is reserved", not this CORS business.

Furthermore, when I run the same query from my node server, I do get a proper error message.  This makes me wonder if the problem is related to reactjs somehow.

Is there any way to get a proper error message in my development environment as I've described?  Thanks.

Edit:

As requested in the comments, here's a typical way I grab the data.  Please note that this is a working query, so this is not generating an error.  As I'm developing, though, this would be the type of query where I'd be making mistakes and not seeing good feedback.

```
// define tableName, indexName

async componentDidMount() {
    // properties include an initiated docClient and organizationId

    const [posts] = await Promise.all([ // typically I will fetch more than just posts (omitted for brevity)
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
            this.props.docClient.query(
                {
                    TableName: tableName,
                    IndexName: indexName,
                    KeyConditionExpression: 'SortKey = :sortKey',
                    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                        ':sortKey': this.props.organizationId + delimiter + 'POST-Date'
                    },
                    ProjectionExpression: 'chatTitle, creatorName, creatorEmail, PostId, creationTime, #text, #data, lastModifiedTime, #status, mentions, attachments, chatType, creatorType',
                    ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#text': 'text', '#status': 'status', '#data': 'Data' }
                },
                (err, data) => {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                        return;
                    }

                    resolve(data.Items);
                }
            )
        )
    ]);

    // do something with posts, etc...
}
```

docClient is generated in a component using:

```
new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'})
```

where AWS is the aws-sdk module

Comment: are you using the dynamodb doc client or the regular one? can we see your code and how you are calling the sdk?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  See the updated question.  I'm not sure what you mean by "regular" doc client.

Comment: the regular one or older one is just created by writing: `new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'})` and the calls are a bit different like `putItem` vs `put` with the doc client so wanted to make sure you were using the correct call with the client you chose. But if i were hitting dynamo from a react app, I would use amplify to make sure my front end is secure and it's much easier libraries to set up and integrate into an app. have you seen it before? https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/react

Comment: Yes, I intend to migrate, but this should still work I think...

Comment: I wonder if this could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28706211/1432640) be your answer...